# UIApplication sharedAppication error: program seems to be accessing wrong file

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, objective-c-2.0, uiapplicationdelegate

in my MainViewController implementation, I need to access variables from two different classes. one of the classes is the AppDelegate and the other is the FlipsideViewController.
the way I accessed these was through this code:

```
-(void)someMethod
{
MyApplicationAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
FlipsideViewController *viewController = (FlipsideViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

then I have an array I access from my application delegate, and some instance variables that return values from an instance of UISwitch from the flipsideViewController:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)appdelegate.originalArray];
for (id element in array)
{
    if ([[element attribute] isEqualToString:@"someAttribute"] && [viewController.switch1 isOn] == YES)
    {
    //preform function
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error message "-[MyApplicationAppDelegate switch1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. terminating app due to uncaught exception"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; will always return the (singleton) instance of `MyApplicationAppDelegate` class and you cannot simply cast it to `FlipsideViewController*`. to access flipsidecontroller value (assuming it is stored in your appdelegate) you can define a property and call it:

```
-(void)somemethod{
     MyApplicationAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     FlipsideViewController *viewController = appDelegate.flipsideController;
}
```

Comment: the switch1 value is not stored in my appdelegate, it comes from the FlipsideViewController class.

Comment: What is happening is that when you call `viewController.switch1` (same as `[viewController switch1]` viewController is not really your controller because you assigned it improperty. Instead viewController is set to MyApplicationAppDelegate because you assigned viewController here: `viewController = (FlipsideViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` Basically you assigned the application delegate itself to viewController not the controller! You need something like `viewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].myViewController;`